# python pdfkit saving from local file fails when the file is larger than 20mb

Tags: python, windows, pdfkit

I have a folder with many txt files. Every time I tried to save the files larger than 20mb as pdf using pdfkit, it fails. It opens an error window with two options of debug, close program. once I click on debug, it doesnt do anything.

Anyone else also experienced the same issue?

I am using jupyter python 3 on windows.

Comment: have you tried upgrade your `wkhtmltopdf` executable?

Comment: I downloaded the latest version. still have the same problem

Comment: I guess you'd better also report this issue to wkhtmltopdf devs.